# How to display file copy progress in 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, nsfilemanager

[FSCopyObjectAsync](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSCopyObjectAsync) is Deprecated in OS X v10.8, Now how to display progress indictor for file copy operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer assumes you're talking about showing the progress of a *single file* being copied.

Yes, "`FSCopyObjectAsync`" been deprecated but it's not gone yet.

And as you have discovered, Apple has not yet provided a useful replacement for the functionality that will eventually be removed.  I suspect (but do not know for certain) that when the new functionality comes in, perhaps for 10.9, it will be delivered in the "`NSFileManagerDelegate`" protocol for delegates to make use of.

To make certain of that, Apple needs to be aware there are lots of developers need this. File a bug report at http://bugreporter.apple.com -- it'll likely be closed as a duplicate, but every vote counts.

Answer (score 2):

[copyfile(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/copyfile.3.html) is alternative for FSCopyObjectAsync. [Here](https://github.com/rustle/RSTLCopyOperation/blob/master/Copy/RSTLCopyOperation.m) is example of copyfile(3) with Progress Callback.

Answer (score 1):

I created an open source project addressing this issue, I wrapped copy file(3) on a NSOperation and created a gui for it, please check it out and maybe contribute to make it better.

https://github.com/larod/FileCopyDemo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Coping files with progressIndicator in C

```
#define BUFSIZE (64*1024)

void *thread_proc(void *arg);
      {
          //outPath & inPatn an NSString paths

          char buffer[BUFSIZE];
          const char * outputFile = [outPath UTF8String];
          const char * inputFile = [inPath UTF8String];
          int in = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY);
          int out = open(outputFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

          vvolatile off_t progress;
          progress = 0;             
          ssize_t bytes_read;
          double fileSize = 0;
          NSNumber * theSize;

          if ([inPath getResourceValue:&theSize forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil])
                  fileSize = [theSize doubleValue];

          [progressIndicator setMaxValue:fileSize];      
          while((bytes_read = read(in, buffer, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
          {
              write(out, buffer, BUFSIZE);
              progress += bytes_read;

              [progressIndicator setDoubleValue:progress];

          }
          // copy is done, or an error occurred
          close(in);
          close(out);
      }
```