# File copy with progress indicator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nsprogressindicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display file copy progress in 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705491/how-to-display-file-copy-progress-in-10-8)

I found "[COCOA TUTORIAL: FILE COPY WITH PROGRESS INDICATOR](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/05/03/cocoa-tutorial-file-copy-with-progress-indicator/)", but in this tutorial used File Manager Reference function which deprecated in OS X 10.8 (FSFileOperationScheduleWithRunLoop...). 
Anybody know how to copy files with `NSProgressIdicator` object?